# Electronically switched decade resistance box design

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, design, resistance

I'd like to design a decade resistance box that uses a microcontroller to control the resistance.

Would it be possible to switch between different valued resistors using transistors? (or another component?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Transistors are not a good choice; they can't handle AC, and DC in only one direction. That's not the way to emulate a resistor.

I would build a chain of 20 resistors, each double the previous one, so 1 \$\Omega\$, 2 \$\Omega\$, 4 \$\Omega\$, 8 \$\Omega\$, etc. By shorting selectively resistors you can create any value between 1 \$\Omega\$ and 1 M\$\Omega\$ with just those 20 values.

Use a reed relays parallel to each resistor.

[This reed relay](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Coto%20Technology%20PDFS/9000_Spartan_Series.pdf) needs only 10 mA at 5 V, so can be driven directly by the microcontroller. Nick correctly points out that you have to check if the total current doesn't exceed the controller's capabilities. But at 20 \$\times\$ 10 mA we would stay way below the maximum of 300 mA for the [ATMega8](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2486.pdf), for instance.

You can use latching relays, so that you can use the resistor without power supply. The price is higher than the reed relay (3.14 dollar vs. 1.20 dollar), and you need either extra logic, or twice the I/Os for driving them.

**edit**, re *jippie*'s suggestion.
*jippie* suggests to use an R-2R ladder, so that only two different resistor values are needed. Though I felt immediately that this wouldn't work it took me a few minutes to understand why not. First intuition. An N-bit ladder network consists of (N+1) 2R resistors, and (N-1) R resistors. Without exact calculations, the largest resistor value you can create with these is always less than 2N \$\times\$ R, that's when you place the all in series. The smallest value is when they're all parallel, and that's always larger than R / (2N). So the ratio between largest and smallest is less than (2N)\$^2\$, which for 20 bits is 1600, and not 2\$^N\$, or 1048 576 as expected. How come? Because an R-2R ladder is **ratiometric**, i.e. the output depends on the ratio between two resistor values, and then you have a lot more possibilities. That's not what we have here; our network has just two nodes, not three. So it's a pity, but R-2R won't work.

Comment: I was thinking latching relays, so the decade box can maintain state when unplugged. Buffer the micro outputs with a mosfet?

Comment: @Alex - latching relays are expensive, you'll have to see what it's worth to you. [This reed relay](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Coto%20Technology%20PDFS/9000_Spartan_Series.pdf) needs only 10 mA at 5 V, so can be driven directly by a microcontroller, and is only 1.20 dollar, 20 price.

Comment: I found a 5V latching relay that'll switch at 28mA (and up to 60W!) for $2.29 [here](http://docs-asia.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0b64/0900766b80b642f5.pdf) (and the cheapest reed relay I can find is $1.30 AUD). Thanks for the link, 10mA is pretty nice - I'll bear that in mind for future projects.

Comment: @Alex - 2.30 dollar is a very nice price, better than what I found at Digikey. Keep in mind that you'll need extra logic to drive them, not just for the 28 mA.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the challenge of shift registers/i2c expanders/muxs!

Comment: 10mA coil current isn't bad for a relay, but if you need to energize more than 5x relays at the same time, the required current could exceed what a micro can source or sink.  Transistors, MOSFETs and specialized relay driver ICs help.  Latching relays can help too, because they can be flipped one at a time.

Comment: @Nick - valid point, thanks for bringing it up. I added the ATMega8 as an example in my answer, and at least for that one it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, within limitations.  Low Rdson FETs would work as long as the lowest resistance you want to switch is significantly higher than the Rdson, if voltage is always applied one way, and the voltage is within the power supply limits.  If you need the resulting composite resistor to be more arbitrary, then you probably need to use relays.

Answer (score 0):

Combine Steven's relays in his answer, with an [R-2R ladder network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder). This way you only need two different value resistors.

Comment: jippie, unfortunately that won't work. See edit in my answer.

Comment: You had me puzzling for a few moments, but you are right. R-2R doesn't work for resistance as I had in mind. I'll go shame myself in a little corner now.