# Are three SPST switches required to convert two resistors from being in series to being parallel

Tags: resistors, switches, circuit-design, parallel, series

It's straightforward to construct a part of a circuit that contains three resistors and two SPST switches where changing both switches converts the resistors from being in parallel with each other to being in series with each other.  I've played around trying to draw a circuit that has only two resistors and two SPST switches, but I can't seem to find a layout that would permit only two switches to convert two resistors from being in series to being in parallel.  Does it really require three SPST switches to convert the two resistors from being in parallel to being in series?

For three resistors, two SPST switches can convert them from parallel to series.  Assume: --R1--R2--R3--
S1 and S2 are the two switches
Solution: --s1--R1--S2--R2--S1--R3--s2--

Comment: You're right, but I don't have a good enough proof, beyond 'try every configuration and see' to be worthy of an answer. The symmetry is a good clue, whether any resistor terminal has to be moved or not in the reconfiguration. See the answer I made in response to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286743/logarithmically-spaced-resistances-using-switches) question

Comment: Resistors are ALOT cheaper than switches so padding in dummy resistors to use one switch would be cheaper, but I don't follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Itsme2003: Schematic is better than text. There's a built-in, very easy to use schematic editor on the toolbar. Add one in and explain the real problem.

Comment: The real problem that I'm trying to solve is a plumbing problem.  I have two water filters that I need to be able to place in parallel or series.  I'm going to be using ball valves to do the switching.  Because of the parallels between plumbing and electricity, I recognized that a solution to the electronics problem would also provide a solution to the plumbing problem.  I thought that three would be the minimum required, but I was hoping that perhaps there was some tricky configuration that would do it with two.

Comment: +1 for using the electrical analogy for a plumbing problem. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEWuoU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The simplest arrangement is with a DPDT switch.*

Since you seem to be constrained to using SPST switches you will need as many switches as there are contacts in use on the DPDT switch in Figure 1. That's two wired as NC (normally closed) and one NO (normally open) using the reference positions shown in the schematic.

> Are three SPST switches required to convert two resistors from being in series to being parallel?

Yes.

Be very aware - particularly if using high currents or voltages - that replacing the bottom changeover contact with two SPST switches gives you the ability to short out V1 and V2. You would probably need to mechanically tie the levers together to ensure actuation of all three switches simultaneously.

---

**Update after comment in OP**

*I have two water filters that I need to be able to place in parallel or series.*

This is a bit different than your original post suggested. The filters have a directional constraint otherwise you will wash the filtered material out of the filter when you reverse the flow. As a result your electrical analogy requires diodes, not resistors. Also a current source seems more appropriate!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwD6Q7.png)</sup>

*Figure 2: (a) If you could find a 3-port valve you could achieve your aim with two valves. Otherwise three 2-port valves are required. (b) Parallel mode. (c) Series mode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM5IXe.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. The valve count can be reduced to two with the addition of a non-return or "check" valve. If this is of the spring type there will be a drop in pressure across it. In parallel mode it will be closed.*

> I thought that three would be the minimum required, but I was hoping that perhaps there was some tricky configuration that would do it with two.

There you go!

Comment: Updated to use only two valves!