# Building a numeric potentiometer for AC current

Tags: ac, load

I'm building a bench to calibrate a device that measures AC currents. As I won't build something accurate, the current will be measured with a current clamp and a multimeter (voltage mode).

For the current load, I first tried a diode bridge with big capacitors and after it, a DC current load (voltage / current converter).

The result is a non sinusoïdal voltage at the clamp output due to the diode voltage which leads to 0 current when the input voltage is less than twice the diode voltage. Like in this screenshot (orange = input voltage, yellow = clamp output (volt)).

[image]

The problem is that the multimeter does not integrate correctly the non sinusoïdal voltage of the clamp and outputs a wrong rms value. If I plug the multimeter in-line as an ampere meter, the measure is correct but I need the clamp because I will measure currents that are beyond what the multimeter can do

That's why I want to build a device that operates likes a rheostat. Its resistance should be defined by a microcontroler and the current vaweform should be proportionnal to the voltage waveform.
Maximum dissipated power is around 60W (for the purpose of my specific design, I can add a serie resistor to drop the power in the device down to 20W)
Input voltage: 6V 50Hz AC sinusoïdal.

How can I do?

Comment: how about resistors? They behave like resistors!

Comment: I would need an infinite number of them. User can choose the value.

Comment: Do you mean a potentiometer or a rheostat i.e. a programmable load?

Comment: I suppose what you want to do is actually an AC active load, basically a power resistor with user-settable value, correct?

Comment: Julien. What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Why can you not use a triac controlled dimmer to vary the output voltage? Does it have to be a sinewave output? Please add the information into your question.

Comment: A finite number of resistors will be fine. Don't forget that you will have a tolerance to work to, say +/- 10%, so you can employ approximations. Look at [this Q/A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286743/logarithmically-spaced-resistances-using-switches) for instance

Comment: @Andyaka: programmable load

Comment: @peufeu: correct

Comment: @Transistor: very good question.  I'm building a bench to calibrate a device that measures AC currents. As I won't build something accurate, the current will be measured with a current clamp and a multimeter (voltage mode). The fact is, when I use this setup and the above current load, the multimeter does not integrate correctly the non sinusoïdal current of the clamp and outputs a wrong rms value. If I plug the multimeter in-line as an ampere meter, the measure is correct but I need the clamp because I will measure currents that are beyond what the multimeter can do.

Comment: Please update your question with the correct details and add your comments in reply to @transistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will interpret this as an AC electronic/active load, basically a "resistor emulator" for AC. I'm thinking about several solutions:

- Oldskool

Several relays, switching resistors of values in powers of 2 in parallel or in series. Basically a 4-bit number, and each bit controls a resistor. Say you have 4 relays, and resistors of 1,2,4,8 ohms.

If they're in series you can make any value between 1 and 15 ohms.

If they're in parallel, then the binary number controls the inverse of the resistor value, which is basically the current.

- Simple PWm

In this case we would generate a PWM signal, switching a low value resistor in circuit with an AC switch (like a pair of back to back FETs).

Current is proportional to V/R multiplied by the duty cycle, which makes this an adjustable resistor.

Add a LC for smoothing...

Comment: In fact, the old school version is already my backup version if I can't find anything better. What do you mean by "back to back fet"? I asked google and he tells me about babies and pregnancy...

Comment: check figure 3 on this [link](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/industrial_strength/archive/2016/07/26/a-modern-approach-to-solid-state-relay-design) -- MOSFETs have body diodes so if you want to switch AC you need 2 FETs to be able to block both polarities. Driving the gates is annoying though, need a floating driver.